# Why can't I access the properties of a HTML div/jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, object

We're creating an HTML page by pulling data from a JSON file. This works fine and we're dynamically creating a list of collapsibles with info using jQuery Mobile.

Now we're trying to get the offset property of each bit of data so we can link to it directly from other pages.

The problem is we can't seem to get hold of the offset value. Using this code:

```
  var entry = $("#" + glosID);
  console.log(entry);
  var offsetJS = entry.offsetTop;
  var offsetJQ = entry.offset().top;
  console.log("Offset from top(JS): " + offsetJS);
  console.log("Offset from top(jQuery): " + offsetJQ);
```

The output is

```
Offset from top(JS): undefined 
Offset from top(jQuery): 0
```

I noticed that inspecting the object in the console shows that it has the structure:

```
div.0: listofproperties
```

So I tried

```
var offsetJS = entry[0].offsetTop;
var offsetJQ = entry[0].offset().top;
```

and now I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'offset'
```

Finally I tried this:

```
  var offsetJS = entry[0].offsetTop;
  var offsetJQ = entry[0].draggable;
```

Now this is interesting. I chose "draggable" because it was the first easy property I found. I tested this with lots of the others I found and they all work. With this code I get:

```
Offset from top(JS): 0 
Offset from top(jQuery): false
```

I've tested lots of other properties using the [0] notification (e.g. namespaceURI) as I'm clearly accessing the first object in an array. But try as I might I cannot get hold of the offset, nor any other property related to the offset (like offsetHeight). I can, however, get other numbers, like nodeType.

What is going on here? Is jQuery mobile messing with things?

Comment: Do you know what the difference between a jQuery object and a DOM Element is?

Comment: if that element is inside a _collapsible_ and it's _collapsed_, `offset().top` will return `0` because it's hidden. check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/tXg7x/) scroll down and click words with red border.

Comment: The element isn't in the collapsible, it's the title text of the collapsible that you click to open the collapsible.

Comment: is it within the active page? or in another page?

Comment: It's in another page, but the page has been built.

Comment: The other page is hidden, you cant retrieve `offset().top` value. Page should be shown in order to retrieve position and dimension of any element.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery instances and DOM objects are not the same thing. `$("#" + glosID)` gives you a jQuery instance, which has the method `offset`; it *contains* a DOM element (provided there was a match for the `id`), which has the property `offsetTop`. So:

```
var entry = $("#" + glosID);
var offsetJS = entry[0].offsetTop; // Note the [0], to get the contained DOM element
var offsetJQ = entry.offset().top; // No [0] on this one, we're using the jQuery instance
console.log("Offset from top(JS): " + offsetJS);
console.log("Offset from top(jQuery): " + offsetJQ);
```

jQuery instances are wrappers around *sets* of DOM elements (well, usually DOM elements; there are some edge cases where jQuery objects are wrappers around other things). A jQuery instance may contain zero or more DOM elements. If you need to access a DOM element inside a jQuery object, you can do that with bracketed notation and a 0-based index (so the first contained element is at `[0]`, the second at `[1]`, etc.).

The "getter" functions of jQuery instances (like `offset()`) will get the information from the *first* element in the set, if the jQuery instance isn't empty (they typically return `undefined` if the set is empty). (In contrast, the "setter" methods set the value on *all* elements in the set.)

Comment: How do I get to the offset value then? If I use offset().top to try and  get the value from the first element (which is what I need) I get 0. I know this isn't correct as I can see the values in the console.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect: `$(...).offset().top` will give you the offset of the first matched element in the set, relative to the document. Note this is not the same as `offsetTop`, which is relative to the offset parent (rather than document). The equivalent of that in jQuery is `.position().top`.

Comment: It doesn't work though, and only gives 0. as you can see from my first code example.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect: Then `0` is probably the correct value. I don't know what to tell you, fundamentally it works: http://jsbin.com/vakiqizo/1

Comment: Hmmm. I think this is due to jQuery Mobile not having built the page fully when I go it. Experimenting with constructing the page before we see it now.

Comment: because elements are hidden, `offset().top` returns `0`. @SubjectiveEffect

Comment: Any way to "unhide" them?

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect: Normally if you measure the elements once the page is loaded (so your script is in a tag at the very end of the page, or you use `ready`), you're fine. But all of this is unrelated to the question you actually asked, which has been answered. If you have a situation where you're not getting the value you expect, ask a new question with the details of that situation. *This* question was about confusion between jQuery and DOM objects, which I believe I've cleared up above.

Comment: You could also add "`offset()`, `position()`, `height()`, etc... will return `0` for elements with `display: none;`" :)

Comment: Thanks guys. If we get it working we'll let you know.